# How to count all rows in a data table c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb, oledbconnection

So I am creating a messaging application for a college project and I have a database of Users in Access, I have linked the database correctly and can execute statements but I am struggling with one problem, how to count the number of rows in a data table.

In fact, all I want to do is to count the total number of users and my teacher told me to get the data into a DataTable and count the number of rows. However, no matter how many users I have in the database, it always returns as 2.

```
int UserCount = 0;

        using (OleDbConnection cuConn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            cuConn.ConnectionString = @"DATASOURCE";
            string statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users";

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(statement, cuConn);
            DataTable Results = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(Results);
            if (Results.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                UserCount = int.Parse(Results.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            }
        }
```

The above code is a copy of what I was sent by my teacher who said it would work. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, sorry if this is a waste of time, still getting used to this StackOverflow thing...

Comment: While not the best way to get that info, this code should work. Unless... are you sure that you are looking at the same database? What is your real connection string?

Comment: You should use a DbCommand or `SELECT * FROM Users` then you can use DataTable.Rows.Count

Comment: @mcNets why you want to retrieve all the rows data just to COUNT them? The query is correct, the better way is to use ExecuteScalar and not all the infrastructure required by the DataAdapter

Comment: Yes, but then use a DbCommand to execute the query.

Comment: I pointed to both, a dbcommand or select *

Answer (score 1):

Try replace `Users` with `[Users]`?
Because `Users` may be a key word of database.
Also the simpler way to get aggregate numbers is by `ExecuteScalar` method.

```
    using (OleDbConnection cuConn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        cuConn.ConnectionString = @"DATASOURCE";
        string statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users]";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (statement, cuConn);
        cuConn.Open();
        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using `using`: do NOT need to close `cuConn` connection... it will be closed then disposed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used your exact code (except the connection string) with sql server so maybe there is a problem with your @"DATASOURCE" or MS Access.